# Bibliography and \cite{} in different files; problem when compiling master file

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, multiple-files

I am writing my dissertation in LaTeX and as it's a long document I have split up the chapters into separate `.tex` files and am compiling them from a master `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{mystyle}
\begin{document}
%front matter
\input{./tex/title.tex}
\input{./tex/abstract.tex}
\tableofcontents
%main matter part 1
\input{./tex/pt_tru.tex}
\input{./tex/ch_itb.tex}
\input{./tex/ch_mech.tex}
\input{./tex/ch_lag.tex}
\input{./tex/ch_tbp.tex}
\input{./tex/ch_kepler.tex}
%main matter part 2
\input{./tex/pt_snc.tex}
\input{./tex/ch_nt.tex}
\input{./tex/ch_conslaws.tex}
%back matter
\input{./tex/ch_appa.tex}
\input{./tex/ch_litrev.tex}
\input{./tex/ch_addlit.tex}
\input{./tex/ch_ack.tex}
\end{document}
```

In the addlit.tex file I am calling the bibliography:

```
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Additional Literature}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Additional Literature}
    \bibliography{dissbib.bib}
    \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

And in various other chapters e.g. `itb.tex` I am citing things from that bibliography:

```
"...necessitating the use of the theory of general relativity \cite{Roseveare}."
```

My problem is that when I compile the master `.tex` file, the citation appears as [?] and the section with the heading "Additional Literature" is blank. How can I solve this problem so that the citations are correct and the bibliography appears?

I am using TexStudio and Bibtex, if that makes any difference.

Edit: my .sty file is

```
\ProvidesPackage{mystyle}
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{parskip} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\usepackage{cite}
```

My .bib file is like this:

```
@book{Roseveare, 
author= {Roseveare, N. T.},
year=1982,
title= {Mercury's Perihelion from Le Verrier to Einstein},
publisher= {Oxford University Press},
```

}

and my .tex files are like this:

```
\chapter{title}
\section{title}
Some text here. Some text here. Some more text here \cite{Roseveare}.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. To fully resolve all cross-references -- and in LaTeX, citation call-outs are set up as cross-references to entries in the bibliography -- it is necessary to run LaTeX, then BibTeX, and then re-run LaTeX *twice more*; a single re-run of LaTeX is not enough. Did you do this four-step process? Does the file `\jobname.blg` contain warning and/or error messages?

Comment: I think Mico's hint is the correct pointer, but if that should not solve the problem, how should we track this issue? Neither `mystyle.sty` isn't available nor the `.bib` nor the various `.tex` files.

Comment: I am not sure as I am very new to LaTex but I think when I compile through TexStudio it runs LaTex then BibTex etc. If not, could you explain how to run Bibtex separately? I get no warnings or error messages. For brevity, I excluded my .sty .bib and .tex files, but I will edit the question to add these.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @NatalieHogg: TeXStudio is a Mac - Application, isn't it? Either it's not configured correctly or you have to switch to console compilation, which should be possible for MAC anyway.

Comment: The fact that the bibliography section contains no entries makes me think you haven't run BibTeX yet. To run BibTeX from TeXstudio, hit "F8". Or, try selecting [Tools] -> [Commands] -> [BibTeX].

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Are you maybe thinking of TeXshop? TeXstudio is definitely available for multiple platforms - including MacOSX.

Comment: @Mico: Maybe I confused it, yes.

Comment: @Mico I have tried what you suggested, now I get some warnings: "citation 'Roseveare' on page 5 undefined" ; "empty 'thebibliography' environment" and "There were undefined references". The document still compiles fine, but my inital problem remains.

Comment: Try omitting the filename extension in the bibliography directive. It should be `\bibliography{dissbib}`, not `\bibliography{dissbib.bib}`. And, do verify that the bib file is named `dissbib.bib` and that it can be found by BibTeX. By the way, what does the file `\jobname.blg` say?

Comment: Ahh thank you! Changing it from dissbib.bib to dissbib has solved it :)

Comment: Glad a solution was found. I'll post my comment as an answer so that the posting may be viewed as having been "officially" answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't mention the filename extension `.bib` in the argument of `\bibliography`. The instruction should be

```
\bibliography{dissbib}
```

rather than `\bibliography{dissbib.bib}`.

Comment: A solution without `lualatex`, I am shocked (+1) ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Hey, it's been almost an entire month since I posted a LuaLaTeX-based answer. (I toyed -- only very briefly! -- with a LuaLaTeX preprocessor-type approach, scanning all input lines and removing any `.bib` substrings in the argument of `\bibliography`. The solution I ended up posting seems a tad simpler, doesn't it?)

Comment: Mico, I love to annoy you about Lua :-P